# C// usage of double pointer of array pointer. not pointer array

Tags: c, pointers

How can I make and use double pointer which point (array pointer)?

I mean double pointer mixed with array pointer..

Would you check last three commented lines?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( char(*)[3]);
void func2( char* (*)[3]); // isit right?:-/

//main has a 2dim array and call a func
int main()
{
  char tst[2][3] = {"abc", "def"};
  func(tst);
  return 0;
}

//and some function take that array's pointer
void func( char(* ap)[3])
{
  func2(&ap??);  // what can be inside ()..?
}

void func2( char* (*ap)[3]) // or char *(*ap[3])???
{
  printf("%s", (*ap)[1]); // confusing,,
}
```

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/lXqY7g)

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you! it was simple than I thought

Comment: @melpomene ok I'll remind it

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all there is a small problem here: `char tst[2][3] = {"abc", "def"};`, you have to allow a '\0' at the end of each string. so `char tst[2][4] = {"abc", "def"};` is necessary.

Then, regarding the pointers, there are 2 concepts here:

1. `char array tst[2][4]` decays to a **pointer to array of 4 chars** when passed as an argument to a function, so that one is correct: func takes an argument of type `char(* ap)[4]`.
2. inside func, ap is such a pointer. So if you want to pass its address to func2, func2 will take as an argument a **pointer to a pointer to array of 4 chars** like so:

   ```
    void func2(char (**ap)[4])
    {
      printf("%s", (*ap)[1]);
    }
   ```